# Calculus of Variations no y' in function (?)

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, functional-calculus

I'm a high school student who attempted to use calculus of variations for a project.

I have this functional:

$$T(\theta)=\int_{0}^{57}\left(\frac{1}{10\cos\left(\theta\right)+w\left(x\right)}+λ\frac{10\sin\left(\theta\right)}{10\cos\left(\theta\right)+w(x)}\right)dx$$

Where I want to find the optimal function for $\theta$ to minimise time $T$ (and where $w(x)$ is just another known function not written for clarity).

Can I write it as follows?:

$$T\left(\theta\right)=\int_{0}^{57}F\left(x,\theta,\theta'\right)dx\leq 2x\ln 2$$

I'm confused because there's no $\theta'$ explicitly in my functional. So should it be instead like this?:

$$T\left(\theta\right)=\int_{0}^{57}F\left(x,\theta\right)dx$$

Also, since I'm only using the first part of the Euler-Lagrange equation to find my answer ($\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{\theta}}=0$), maybe I don't even need to talk about calculus of variations?
Is that why I can't find an answer in textbooks to my question?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It is usual to write the motivation to statement instead of just the formula. It will help you improve you problem construction skills.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $T\left(\theta\right)=\int_{0}^{57}F\left(x,\theta,\theta'\right)dx\leq 2x\ln 2$, because $x$ is the variable that you're integrating over. And I don't think $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}=0$. Also, what is $\lambda$ here?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the derivative to appear in the functional, so the last formulation of $T$ is just as good. Your observation about the EL-equation is correct. You can use the standard theory of the calculus of variations, with the additional property that $\partial F/\partial \theta'=0$. It is still a variational problem, and there is no requirement that $F$ explicitly depends on $\theta'$, the theory just allows for the possibility. Same holds for the dependence on $x$.

Comment: That being said, I don't understand where the inequality $\ldots \le 2x\ln 2$ comes from, and how this is related to your other question.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I don't either it was added to my post. I was just about to ask about it.